# Rubyで文字化けを解消できない

Tags: ruby, 文字化け

Rubyスクリプトで日本語を出力するとSyntax Errorが返ってきます。

おそらく文字コードの問題と推測していますが、すべてUTF-8が設定されていて
問題ないように見え、立ち往生しています。
対処法がおわかりでしたらご教授いただきたく質問します。

■ [ruby] `p "あ"`　出力結果

```
get_tdnet_data.rb:10: Invalid char `\x1B' in expression
get_tdnet_data.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting end-of-input
p "$"(B"
```

■ [console] `ruby --version` 出力結果

```
ruby 2.6.2p47 (2019-03-13 revision 67232) [x86_64-linux]
```

■ [ruby] `puts __ENCODING__`　 出力結果

```
UTF-8
```

■ [vi] :set enc? 出力結果

```
encoding=utf-8
```

■ [Teraterm] Setup > Terminal
受信：UTF-8
送信：UTF-8

■ [CentOS7] `localectl` 出力結果

```
   System Locale: LANG=ja,UTF-8
       VC Keymap: jp106
      X11 Layout: jp
```

■ [CentOS7] `redhat-release` 出力結果

```
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
```

Comment: 「UTF-8が設定されていて」いるにも関わらず、`p "あ"`と入力された文字列は`ISO-2022-JP`相当のバイト列に変換されてしまっているようです。実行環境についてほとんど書かれていないのですが、rubyやviだけでなく、ターミナルソフトの文字コードは確認されましたか?

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。Teratermは受信/送信ともにUTF-8でlocalectlの出力結果もUTF-8でした。追って本文に情報追記します。

Comment: vimで問題のファイルを開いた後、`:set fenc?` の結果はどうなっていますか?

Comment: ありがとうございます。見事にiso-2022-jpでした…これをutf-8にしてみます

Answer (score 0):

皆様ご協力いただきありがとうございました
vimの設定上の問題で
:set fenc=utf-8
で解消できました。